# Samsung NX3000 lens broken ribbon flex cable

Tags: lens, samsung

I was trying to get sand out of my lens and accidentally broke one of the flex cables. I want to fix it myself but I don't know where to get the right replacement for the specific part it was attached to.

Does anyone know the name of this specific lens part and/or cable shape name?

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Edit: This is the 15 - 60 mm lens

Comment: Presumably this is the 16-50mm kit lens?

Comment: "I was trying to get sand out of my lens..." And what lens would that be?

Comment: @mattdm Would that be the 16-50mm f/2-2.8 or the 16-50mm f/3.5-5.6?

Comment: @MichaelClark I meant the latter. Did they sell the faster one as a higher-end kit option?

Comment: I don't know. But looking at Samsung's support site, apparently the lens (along with the body color) is indicated by the specific model name the cameras was sold as: e.g. EV-NX3000BOIGB, The f/3.5-5.6 doesn't look large enough to contain the part in the first photo in the OP.

Comment: Yes. This is the 16-50 mm lens

Answer (score 3):

Since the Samsung NX system is dead, your best bet will probably be to try and find a part scavenged from another example of the same lens. You might get lucky on eBay, but you'll probably need to know the part number. Finding a catalogue number online is pretty much impossible without knowing which specific lens you're talking about.

The fly in the ointment will probably be that ribbon cables are some of the most common parts in a lens to fail (whether by normal wear-and-tear or by mistakes made when disassembling) and thus many or most examples of parted-out lenses will have the same issue yours does.

Good luck!